# Facebook AccessToken returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can no longer `sign-in-with-Facebook` inside my app as `AcessToken` return nil...

Here is my `function`:

```
let accessToken = AccessToken.current

    guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else {
        print("bruh")
        return
    }
```

It currently `prints` the "bruh".

It was working the other days!

I didn't change anything inside that file. But I changed the **Project Name** and the **Bundle Identifier**. Could this have anything to do with the error?

**UPDATE:** I deleted the old Facebook-Project and created a new one with the correct `Bundle-ID`. I also changed the **ID** and **Secret Token** inside Firebase.

Is there anything else I need to do??? really annoying ...
Is there maybe a way to show an error to see what the actual problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue! The problem was that I had the old **ID** inside my `info.plist`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be about changing of `Bundle Identifier`,

You should set the new one on https://developers.facebook.com/

[image]